# Converting opamp output

Tags: operational-amplifier, temperature

I want to measure the temperature with PT100. At the first stage the resistance is converted to voltage (ca in range 1.5-2 V for 0°C 100°C). How can i scale this voltage to range 0-3.3V with the second opamp (red box)? I want to have 0.3V for 0°C  and 3V for 100°C.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Hej, Emire, zemljače, šta ima?  :D  This is the classical level shifting and scaling with op-amps type of deal.  
Are you able to modify parts of this circuit prior to the IC16a (3rd op-amp)?

Comment: I would strongly suggest a [dedicated IC](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=PT100+amp+IC&t=opera&ia=web) for this. Reason being, the discrete approach will be highly temperature-dependent unless carefully designed.

Comment: @EdinFifić Pozz zemo. Yes, the parts could be changed.